# Assignment is not giving expected result while assigning different class of objects

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, assignment-operator

In the code snippet below I am assigning a object of type `Box` into an object of type `Circle` through the assignment operator, but I am not able to get the expected result.

Current execution result:
circle=6
box=0

Expected result:
circle=6
box=0.7

As per below code snippet, the assignment operator is responsible for initializing the `Box` object so that it can be assigned to the `Circle` object. After initialization, the `Circle` class function `getAreaBox` (member of `Circle` class) will call the `getAreabox` (member of `Box` class) in order to get the currently set value inside the `Circle` class constructor. It looks like proper initialization is not happening inside the assignment operator and due to this the expected value is not returned by the `getAreabox` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box
{
private:
  double area;

  public:
  Box(double areaval=0.0)
  {
    area=areaval;
  }
  double getAreabox() const
  {
    return area;
  }
};


class Circle
{
private:
  int area;
  Box *box;

public:
  Circle(int areaval=0,double boxval=0.0):area(areaval)
  {
    box= new Box(boxval);
  }

  const Circle& operator =(const Box& obj)
  {
    if(&obj!=box)
    {
      delete box;
      box= new Box (obj);
    }

    return *this;
  }

  int getAreaCircle() 
  {
    return area;
  }

  double getAreaBox()
  { 
    double val=box->getAreabox();
    return val;
  }

  ~Circle(){delete box;}
};



int main() {
  Box box;
  Circle circle(6,0.7);
  cout<<"circle="<<circle.getAreaCircle()<<endl;
  circle=box;
  cout<<"box="<<circle.getAreaBox()<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So when you replace `Box box;` with `Box box(0.8);`  You'll notice that it prints `box=0.8`  Your assignment operators seem to be doing exactly what you ask them to

Comment: I think you should clarify exactly why you think the expected output is box=0; but before you do so step through everything with a debugger.

Comment: Please pay attention to the question preview when posting; the code was a total mess indentation-wise.

Comment: code was indented through ctrl+k

Comment: Unfortunately that shortcut isn't magic, and in particular doesn't work well with tabs. Please always check the question preview.

Comment: Now on wards will format the code in eclipse (ctrl+shift+F) and (ctrl+I) and then paste the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on my solution in below link for your problem.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bfb63a8eedeefae

resolution update:

(1) Raw pointer is replaced with smart pointers.

(2) copy assignment operator is replaced with getObject method in order to get the current set Box class object inside constructor.

(3) You needn't to set current value again with box object constructor as it will pick the same value set in Circle class constructor.

(4) No need to have  method double getAreaBox() separately in Circle class so code is optimized for the same.

I hope this solution will take care of your need .

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. I have customize your solution little bit based on my requirement. Below is the link for the same, so now no need to even create empty  box object in main function and apart from this i would like to continue with getAreaBox function so that i would be able to instantiate this method with Circle class object. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b823ba2690590454

Comment: Agree with you :). we shouldn't expose Box object in main function itself as it doesn't look good as Circle object is already have responsibility to initialize the same and default value initialization is already done  in Box class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does exactly what it is supposed to do. Your expectations are wrong. You expect box = 0.7, but you overwrite box with the statement

```
circle=box;
```

The copy constructor destructs the old box inside circle and creates a new one as a copy of 'box'. What value does 'box' have?

Since you default initialise 'box' in your main

```
Box box;
```

and the default is 0, the program will print 0 in the last cout statement.

```
cout << "box=" << circle.getAreaBox() << endl;
```

will print the value of the box inside the circle ... which has been initialised via copy constructor from the variable 'box'.

If you change the variable 'box' in main to:

```
int main() {
  Box box(0.9);
...
```

The output will be:

```
circle=6, box=0.9
```

P.S. Please don't use pointers (`Box*`). Just don't. Use `std::shared_ptr<>` instead. There are ton's of good websites explaining the reasons. Your class 'circle' has a lot of pointer related issues. You can improve your programming skills by reading about

- dangling pointer
- `deep copy` vs. `shallow copy`
- `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std::unique_ptr<`>
- virtual desctructors

Have fun...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestions. inside Circle class destructor I am already deleting the box object. Could you through some light where you have observed pointer related issues.